# Execution from 1 to 1 mapped page

Tags: windows, x86, kernel, shellcode, windows-kernel

I allocate page with MmAllocateContiguousMemory and get page physical address.

I add 1 to 1 mapping to page table (new virtual address is the same as physical address).

New virtual address has bits 32-63 cleared.

I write shellcode to new virtual address.

I try to execute shellcode and get KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE.

If I where to map physical address to some virtual address in kernel address range shellcode would execute fine.

How this protection/behavior is called?

I thought it was SMEP but disabling it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it just happened that pml4 entry already existed and had nx bit set.